# Isolate values in a comma delimited field using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I've been working in SSIS trying to parse a multi-valued excel spreadsheet field using VB.Net.  My script works by searching for a comma, then using string functions (Left, Right) to whittle down the string until it's null.

Is there an SSIS toolbox function that will do that for me?  If so, please tell me :)

Using Visual Studio 2019, Excel 2016.

Comment: To restate: For a given string with multiple commas, is there a way to chunk it up into the delimited blocks?

Comment: Kind of.  There are multiple commas (sometimes even a trailing comma).  I wrote a VB.Net script to parse, which works, but is very slow.  I was just hoping for maintainability purposes to find a tool in the SSIS Toolbox that 'd do it for me.  I found that answer, which is below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I personally use c# script component for this.

```
string textToSplit = Row.[Your Column].Value;
string[] splits = textToSplit.Split(','); 

//Now you can work with all sections

foreach(string split in splits)
{
    //This is where you do something with each part
}
```

If the strings are quote wrapped or have commas inside the pieces then you have to use a more complicated splitter utilizing REGEX.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I figured it out - it's to use the derived column transformation within the data flow task.  With it I can use LEFT and RIGHT functions to parse.  I appreciate the help with the C# code - my VB.Net code is very similar.  Going to test on Monday!

Comment: Oh. So you only have one comma?